# Unwanted repeating textures

Tags: texturing, image

I'm working on an Earth model and when I apply its textures I get them repeating instead of being applied only once. Im still new to Blender, I would appreciate some help [image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your sphere isn't UV-unwrapped.
You need to enter edit mode, select all vertices, press "U" on your keyboard and then choose a projection mode that fits your texture. I'd guess that "equirectangular" might be the correct option.